# LNK2019, LNK 1120 ошибка линковки VS2015 С++

Tags: c++

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl three_des_crypt(unsigned char * const,unsigned char * const,unsigned char (* const)[16][6])" (?three_des_crypt@@YAXQAE0QAY1BA@5E@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl EncryptPassword(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &)" (?EncryptPassword@@YAXAAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z)  EmulatorTop C:\Users\Ilya\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\EmulatorTop\ThreadEvents\crypto.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl three_des_key_schedule(unsigned char * const,unsigned char (* const)[16][6],unsigned int)" (?three_des_key_schedule@@YAXQAEQAY1BA@5EI@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl EncryptPassword(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &)" (?EncryptPassword@@YAXAAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) EmulatorTop C:\Users\Ilya\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\EmulatorTop\ThreadEvents\crypto.obj 1   
Error   LNK1120 2 unresolved externals  EmulatorTop C:\Users\Ilya\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\EmulatorTop\Debug\EmulatorTop.exe   1
```

crypt.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CRYPT_H
#define CRYPT_H
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "des.h"

using namespace std;

 void EncryptPassword(string&, string&);
#endif
```

crypto.cpp

```
#include "crypt.h"

 void EncryptPassword(string& key, string& str) 
{
    uchar schedule[3][16][6],
        out[8],
        uKey[24],
        uText[8];
    strcpy((char*) (uKey), key.c_str());
    strcpy((char*)(uText), str.c_str());

    three_des_key_schedule(uKey, schedule, 1);
    three_des_crypt(uText,out, schedule);

}
```

des.h

```
#ifndef DES_C
#define DES_C



#define uchar unsigned char
#define uint unsigned int
#define ENCRYPT 1
#define DECRYPT 0

// Obtain bit "b" from the left and shift it "c" places from the right
#define BITNUM(a,b,c) (((a[(b)/8] >> (7 - (b%8))) & 0x01) << (c))
#define BITNUMINTR(a,b,c) ((((a) >> (31 - (b))) & 0x00000001) << (c))
#define BITNUMINTL(a,b,c) ((((a) << (b)) & 0x80000000) >> (c))
// This macro converts a 6 bit block with the S-Box row defined as the first and last
// bits to a 6 bit block with the row defined by the first two bits.
#define SBOXBIT(a) (((a) & 0x20) | (((a) & 0x1f) >> 1) | (((a) & 0x01) << 4))

//extern uchar sbox1[64];
//uchar sbox2[64];
//uchar sbox3[64];
//uchar sbox4[64];
//uchar sbox5[64];
//uchar sbox6[64];
//uchar sbox7[64];
//uchar sbox8[64];


void key_schedule(uchar key[], uchar schedule[][6], uint mode);

// Initial (Inv)Permutation step
void IP(uint state[], uchar in[]);

void InvIP(uint state[], uchar in[]);

uint f(uint state, uchar key[]);

void des_crypt(uchar in[], uchar out[], uchar key[][6]);

/**************************************
             3DES functions
**************************************/

void three_des_key_schedule(uchar key[], uchar schedule[][16][6], uint mode);


void three_des_crypt(uchar in[], uchar out[], uchar key[][16][6]);

/************************************/

#endif // !DES_C
```

des.cpp

```
#include "des.h"




void key_schedule(uchar key[], uchar schedule[][6], uint mode)
{
    uint i, j, to_gen, C, D,
        key_rnd_shift[16] = { 1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1 },
        key_perm_c[28] = { 56,48,40,32,24,16,8,0,57,49,41,33,25,17,
        9,1,58,50,42,34,26,18,10,2,59,51,43,35 },
        key_perm_d[28] = { 62,54,46,38,30,22,14,6,61,53,45,37,29,21,
        13,5,60,52,44,36,28,20,12,4,27,19,11,3 },
        key_compression[48] = { 13,16,10,23,0,4,2,27,14,5,20,9,
        22,18,11,3,25,7,15,6,26,19,12,1,
        40,51,30,36,46,54,29,39,50,44,32,47,
        43,48,38,55,33,52,45,41,49,35,28,31 };

    // Permutated Choice #1 (copy the key in, ignoring parity bits).
    for (i = 0, j = 31, C = 0; i < 28; ++i, --j)
        C |= BITNUM(key, key_perm_c[i], j);
    for (i = 0, j = 31, D = 0; i < 28; ++i, --j)
        D |= BITNUM(key, key_perm_d[i], j);

    // Generate the 16 subkeys.
    for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        C = ((C << key_rnd_shift[i]) | (C >> (28 - key_rnd_shift[i]))) & 0xfffffff0;
        D = ((D << key_rnd_shift[i]) | (D >> (28 - key_rnd_shift[i]))) & 0xfffffff0;

        // Decryption subkeys are reverse order of encryption subkeys so
        // generate them in reverse if the key schedule is for decryption useage.
        if (mode == DECRYPT)
            to_gen = 15 - i;
        else
            to_gen = i;
        // Initialize the array
        for (j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
            schedule[to_gen][j] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 24; ++j)
            schedule[to_gen][j / 8] |= BITNUMINTR(C, key_compression[j], 7 - (j % 8));
        for (; j < 48; ++j)
            schedule[to_gen][j / 8] |= BITNUMINTR(D, key_compression[j] - 28, 7 - (j % 8));
    }
}

void IP(uint state[], uchar in[])
{
    state[0] = BITNUM(in, 57, 31) | BITNUM(in, 49, 30) | BITNUM(in, 41, 29) | BITNUM(in, 33, 28) |
        BITNUM(in, 25, 27) | BITNUM(in, 17, 26) | BITNUM(in, 9, 25) | BITNUM(in, 1, 24) |
        BITNUM(in, 59, 23) | BITNUM(in, 51, 22) | BITNUM(in, 43, 21) | BITNUM(in, 35, 20) |
        BITNUM(in, 27, 19) | BITNUM(in, 19, 18) | BITNUM(in, 11, 17) | BITNUM(in, 3, 16) |
        BITNUM(in, 61, 15) | BITNUM(in, 53, 14) | BITNUM(in, 45, 13) | BITNUM(in, 37, 12) |
        BITNUM(in, 29, 11) | BITNUM(in, 21, 10) | BITNUM(in, 13, 9) | BITNUM(in, 5, 8) |
        BITNUM(in, 63, 7) | BITNUM(in, 55, 6) | BITNUM(in, 47, 5) | BITNUM(in, 39, 4) |
        BITNUM(in, 31, 3) | BITNUM(in, 23, 2) | BITNUM(in, 15, 1) | BITNUM(in, 7, 0);

    state[1] = BITNUM(in, 56, 31) | BITNUM(in, 48, 30) | BITNUM(in, 40, 29) | BITNUM(in, 32, 28) |
        BITNUM(in, 24, 27) | BITNUM(in, 16, 26) | BITNUM(in, 8, 25) | BITNUM(in, 0, 24) |
        BITNUM(in, 58, 23) | BITNUM(in, 50, 22) | BITNUM(in, 42, 21) | BITNUM(in, 34, 20) |
        BITNUM(in, 26, 19) | BITNUM(in, 18, 18) | BITNUM(in, 10, 17) | BITNUM(in, 2, 16) |
        BITNUM(in, 60, 15) | BITNUM(in, 52, 14) | BITNUM(in, 44, 13) | BITNUM(in, 36, 12) |
        BITNUM(in, 28, 11) | BITNUM(in, 20, 10) | BITNUM(in, 12, 9) | BITNUM(in, 4, 8) |
        BITNUM(in, 62, 7) | BITNUM(in, 54, 6) | BITNUM(in, 46, 5) | BITNUM(in, 38, 4) |
        BITNUM(in, 30, 3) | BITNUM(in, 22, 2) | BITNUM(in, 14, 1) | BITNUM(in, 6, 0);
}

void InvIP(uint state[], uchar in[])
{
    in[0] = BITNUMINTR(state[1], 7, 7) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 7, 6) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 15, 5) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[0], 15, 4) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 23, 3) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 23, 2) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[1], 31, 1) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 31, 0);

    in[1] = BITNUMINTR(state[1], 6, 7) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 6, 6) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 14, 5) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[0], 14, 4) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 22, 3) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 22, 2) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[1], 30, 1) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 30, 0);

    in[2] = BITNUMINTR(state[1], 5, 7) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 5, 6) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 13, 5) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[0], 13, 4) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 21, 3) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 21, 2) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[1], 29, 1) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 29, 0);

    in[3] = BITNUMINTR(state[1], 4, 7) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 4, 6) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 12, 5) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[0], 12, 4) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 20, 3) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 20, 2) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[1], 28, 1) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 28, 0);

    in[4] = BITNUMINTR(state[1], 3, 7) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 3, 6) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 11, 5) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[0], 11, 4) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 19, 3) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 19, 2) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[1], 27, 1) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 27, 0);

    in[5] = BITNUMINTR(state[1], 2, 7) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 2, 6) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 10, 5) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[0], 10, 4) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 18, 3) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 18, 2) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[1], 26, 1) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 26, 0);

    in[6] = BITNUMINTR(state[1], 1, 7) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 1, 6) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 9, 5) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[0], 9, 4) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 17, 3) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 17, 2) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[1], 25, 1) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 25, 0);

    in[7] = BITNUMINTR(state[1], 0, 7) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 0, 6) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 8, 5) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[0], 8, 4) | BITNUMINTR(state[1], 16, 3) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 16, 2) |
        BITNUMINTR(state[1], 24, 1) | BITNUMINTR(state[0], 24, 0);
}

uint f(uint state, uchar key[])
{
    uchar lrgstate[6], i;
    uint t1, t2;

    // Expantion Permutation
    t1 = BITNUMINTL(state, 31, 0) | ((state & 0xf0000000) >> 1) | BITNUMINTL(state, 4, 5) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 3, 6) | ((state & 0x0f000000) >> 3) | BITNUMINTL(state, 8, 11) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 7, 12) | ((state & 0x00f00000) >> 5) | BITNUMINTL(state, 12, 17) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 11, 18) | ((state & 0x000f0000) >> 7) | BITNUMINTL(state, 16, 23);

    t2 = BITNUMINTL(state, 15, 0) | ((state & 0x0000f000) << 15) | BITNUMINTL(state, 20, 5) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 19, 6) | ((state & 0x00000f00) << 13) | BITNUMINTL(state, 24, 11) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 23, 12) | ((state & 0x000000f0) << 11) | BITNUMINTL(state, 28, 17) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 27, 18) | ((state & 0x0000000f) << 9) | BITNUMINTL(state, 0, 23);

    lrgstate[0] = (t1 >> 24) & 0x000000ff;
    lrgstate[1] = (t1 >> 16) & 0x000000ff;
    lrgstate[2] = (t1 >> 8) & 0x000000ff;
    lrgstate[3] = (t2 >> 24) & 0x000000ff;
    lrgstate[4] = (t2 >> 16) & 0x000000ff;
    lrgstate[5] = (t2 >> 8) & 0x000000ff;

    // Key XOR
    lrgstate[0] ^= key[0];
    lrgstate[1] ^= key[1];
    lrgstate[2] ^= key[2];
    lrgstate[3] ^= key[3];
    lrgstate[4] ^= key[4];
    lrgstate[5] ^= key[5];
    uchar sbox1[64] = {
        14,  4,  13,  1,   2, 15,  11,  8,   3, 10,   6, 12,   5,  9,   0,  7,
        0, 15,   7,  4,  14,  2,  13,  1,  10,  6,  12, 11,   9,  5,   3,  8,
        4,  1,  14,  8,  13,  6,   2, 11,  15, 12,   9,  7,   3, 10,   5,  0,
        15, 12,   8,  2,   4,  9,   1,  7,   5, 11,   3, 14,  10,  0,   6, 13
    };
    uchar sbox2[64] = {
        15,  1,   8, 14,   6, 11,   3,  4,   9,  7,   2, 13,  12,  0,   5, 10,
        3, 13,   4,  7,  15,  2,   8, 14,  12,  0,   1, 10,   6,  9,  11,  5,
        0, 14,   7, 11,  10,  4,  13,  1,   5,  8,  12,  6,   9,  3,   2, 15,
        13,  8,  10,  1,   3, 15,   4,  2,  11,  6,   7, 12,   0,  5,  14,  9
    };
    uchar sbox3[64] = {
        10,  0,   9, 14,   6,  3,  15,  5,   1, 13,  12,  7,  11,  4,   2,  8,
        13,  7,   0,  9,   3,  4,   6, 10,   2,  8,   5, 14,  12, 11,  15,  1,
        13,  6,   4,  9,   8, 15,   3,  0,  11,  1,   2, 12,   5, 10,  14,  7,
        1, 10,  13,  0,   6,  9,   8,  7,   4, 15,  14,  3,  11,  5,   2, 12
    };
    uchar sbox4[64] = {
        7, 13,  14,  3,   0,  6,   9, 10,   1,  2,   8,  5,  11, 12,   4, 15,
        13,  8,  11,  5,   6, 15,   0,  3,   4,  7,   2, 12,   1, 10,  14,  9,
        10,  6,   9,  0,  12, 11,   7, 13,  15,  1,   3, 14,   5,  2,   8,  4,
        3, 15,   0,  6,  10,  1,  13,  8,   9,  4,   5, 11,  12,  7,   2, 14
    };
    uchar sbox5[64] = {
        2, 12,   4,  1,   7, 10,  11,  6,   8,  5,   3, 15,  13,  0,  14,  9,
        14, 11,   2, 12,   4,  7,  13,  1,   5,  0,  15, 10,   3,  9,   8,  6,
        4,  2,   1, 11,  10, 13,   7,  8,  15,  9,  12,  5,   6,  3,   0, 14,
        11,  8,  12,  7,   1, 14,   2, 13,   6, 15,   0,  9,  10,  4,   5,  3
    };
    uchar sbox6[64] = {
        12,  1,  10, 15,   9,  2,   6,  8,   0, 13,   3,  4,  14,  7,   5, 11,
        10, 15,   4,  2,   7, 12,   9,  5,   6,  1,  13, 14,   0, 11,   3,  8,
        9, 14,  15,  5,   2,  8,  12,  3,   7,  0,   4, 10,   1, 13,  11,  6,
        4,  3,   2, 12,   9,  5,  15, 10,  11, 14,   1,  7,   6,  0,   8, 13
    };
    uchar sbox7[64] = {
        4, 11,   2, 14,  15,  0,   8, 13,   3, 12,   9,  7,   5, 10,   6,  1,
        13,  0,  11,  7,   4,  9,   1, 10,  14,  3,   5, 12,   2, 15,   8,  6,
        1,  4,  11, 13,  12,  3,   7, 14,  10, 15,   6,  8,   0,  5,   9,  2,
        6, 11,  13,  8,   1,  4,  10,  7,   9,  5,   0, 15,  14,  2,   3, 12
    };
    uchar sbox8[64] = {
        13,  2,   8,  4,   6, 15,  11,  1,  10,  9,   3, 14,   5,  0,  12,  7,
        1, 15,  13,  8,  10,  3,   7,  4,  12,  5,   6, 11,   0, 14,   9,  2,
        7, 11,   4,  1,   9, 12,  14,  2,   0,  6,  10, 13,  15,  3,   5,  8,
        2,  1,  14,  7,   4, 10,   8, 13,  15, 12,   9,  0,   3,  5,   6, 11
    };
    // S-Box Permutation
    state = (sbox1[SBOXBIT(lrgstate[0] >> 2)] << 28) |
        (sbox2[SBOXBIT(((lrgstate[0] & 0x03) << 4) | (lrgstate[1] >> 4))] << 24) |
        (sbox3[SBOXBIT(((lrgstate[1] & 0x0f) << 2) | (lrgstate[2] >> 6))] << 20) |
        (sbox4[SBOXBIT(lrgstate[2] & 0x3f)] << 16) |
        (sbox5[SBOXBIT(lrgstate[3] >> 2)] << 12) |
        (sbox6[SBOXBIT(((lrgstate[3] & 0x03) << 4) | (lrgstate[4] >> 4))] << 8) |
        (sbox7[SBOXBIT(((lrgstate[4] & 0x0f) << 2) | (lrgstate[5] >> 6))] << 4) |
        sbox8[SBOXBIT(lrgstate[5] & 0x3f)];

    // P-Box Permutation
    state = BITNUMINTL(state, 15, 0) | BITNUMINTL(state, 6, 1) | BITNUMINTL(state, 19, 2) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 20, 3) | BITNUMINTL(state, 28, 4) | BITNUMINTL(state, 11, 5) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 27, 6) | BITNUMINTL(state, 16, 7) | BITNUMINTL(state, 0, 8) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 14, 9) | BITNUMINTL(state, 22, 10) | BITNUMINTL(state, 25, 11) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 4, 12) | BITNUMINTL(state, 17, 13) | BITNUMINTL(state, 30, 14) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 9, 15) | BITNUMINTL(state, 1, 16) | BITNUMINTL(state, 7, 17) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 23, 18) | BITNUMINTL(state, 13, 19) | BITNUMINTL(state, 31, 20) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 26, 21) | BITNUMINTL(state, 2, 22) | BITNUMINTL(state, 8, 23) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 18, 24) | BITNUMINTL(state, 12, 25) | BITNUMINTL(state, 29, 26) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 5, 27) | BITNUMINTL(state, 21, 28) | BITNUMINTL(state, 10, 29) |
        BITNUMINTL(state, 3, 30) | BITNUMINTL(state, 24, 31);

    // Return the final state value
    return(state);
}

void des_crypt(uchar in[], uchar out[], uchar key[][6])
{
    uint state[2], idx, t;

    IP(state, in);

    // Loop 16 times, perform the final loop manually as it doesn't switch sides
    for (idx = 0; idx < 15; ++idx) {
        t = state[1];
        state[1] = f(state[1], key[idx]) ^ state[0];
        state[0] = t;
    }
    state[0] = f(state[1], key[15]) ^ state[0];

    // Inverse IP
    InvIP(state, out);
}

void three_des_key_schedule(uchar key[], uchar schedule[][16][6], uint mode)
{
    if (mode == ENCRYPT) {
        key_schedule(&key[0], schedule[0], mode);
        key_schedule(&key[8], schedule[1], !mode);
        key_schedule(&key[16], schedule[2], mode);
    }
    else {
        key_schedule(&key[16], schedule[0], mode);
        key_schedule(&key[8], schedule[1], !mode);
        key_schedule(&key[0], schedule[2], mode);
    }
}

void three_des_crypt(uchar in[], uchar out[], uchar key[][16][6])
{
    des_crypt(in, out, key[0]);
    des_crypt(out, out, key[1]);
    des_crypt(out, out, key[2]);
}
```

Comment: Вы des.cpp в проект не забыли включить?...

Comment: Каким образом?Не понял.

Comment: Откуда я знаю?.. У вас линковщик не находит функции из des.cpp, вот я на всякий случай и спрашиваю :)

Comment: В Solution Explorer des.cpp присутствует.

Comment: пересоберите проект с помощью make

Comment: У вас каким-то образом не компилируется этот файл. Как вы его добавляли? Посмотрите внимательно в свойства.

Comment: Попробуйте в файле des.cpp сделать явную синтаксическую ошибку и посмотрите, найдёт ли её процесс компиляции.

Comment: Создал dess.cpp скопировал в него из des.cpp и о чудо, работает! Кстати, des.cpp добавлял через add->exsisting item